# Locating webelement by link in Selenium java

Tags: selenium

How is it possible to locale Selenium WebElement that is next to certain link?

I have this kind of source code

```
    <a href="/url.com" >
Link text
 </a>
<ul>
<li class="dir">THIS LIST ELEMENT I WANT TO LOCATE
  <ul>
    <li>
```

If the url is not nessesary in locating, feel free to tell me better way! I have had no luck with counting elements, because amount of them varies based on mouse moves. I use Selenium Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xpath You can locate.

```
"//a[text()='Link text']/following-sibling::ul/li[@class='dir']"
```

I assume that a and ul tags are siblings. If those are not siblings then also you can achieve that by modifying above xpath slightly.

```
"//a[text()='Link text']/../following-sibling::ul/li[@class='dir']"
```

Comment: Yes.. you can use any attribute.

Comment: What's wrong with this   WebElement list = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[(@href,'/url/site.com')]/following-sibling::ul/li[@class='dir']"));

Comment: The XPath is wrong. You are trying to use the equals operator...use:  `WebElement list = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/url/site.com']/following-sibling::ul/li[@class='dir']"));`

Comment: You should use contains operator if it is not exactly equal. xpath : "//a[contains(@href,'/url/site.com')]/following-sibling‌​::ul/li[@class='dir']"